# can't pass JWT in RNFS in react-native

Tags: react-native, jwt, pdfview, react-native-fs

**I am using RNFS with PDFView to display PDF.**

> I am trying to download a pdf file from website which have JWT authentication, request is going but there is authentication issue, it is giving 403 response.

**I am doing it as follows,**

```
var pdfPath=this.pdfPath;
alert(pdfDownloadURL)
var DownloadFileOptions={
     fromUrl: pdfDownloadURL,          // URL to download file from
     toFile: pdfPath,         // Local filesystem path to save the file to

     headers: {'Authorization' : DEMO_TOKEN}  // An object of headers to be passed to the server

}
RNFS.downloadFile(DownloadFileOptions).then(res => {
    alert(res)
    this.setState({isPdfDownload: true});
}).catch(err => {
    alert(err);
    this.props.navigator.pop
});
```

Please help me finding solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you append `Bearer `  before the token ?

Comment: @Xeijp I am getting the token after logging in. So I am passing as it is. I fetched other data with fetch() method, but this one using RNFS is not working.